# Adding VPNaaS to an OpenStack Zed setup

Tags: openstack

First of all, sorry if I'm using the wrong category, group or whatever. This is my first every question here.

I've setup Openstack with this documentation https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/ followed by the installation of keystone, glance, nova, neutron, horizon from here https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html#minimal-deployment-for-yoga (except I used zed instead of yoga). Now I managed to install FWaaS from here: https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/zed/admin/fwaas-v2-scenario.html but I also need VPNaaS for my project. When following this guide https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/zed/admin/vpnaas-scenario.html I can't make it work. Everytime I restart neutron it failes

```
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime [req-a32b0298-9d9f-49c9-a0fb-d914020d1edd - - - - -] Error loading class by alias: stevedore.exception.NoMatches: No 'neutron.service_plugins' driver found, looking for 'vpnaas'
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron_lib/utils/runtime.py", line 113, in load_class_by_alias_or_classname
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime     mgr = driver.DriverManager(
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/driver.py", line 53, in __init__
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime     super(DriverManager, self).__init__(
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/named.py", line 89, in __init__
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime     self._init_plugins(extensions)
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/driver.py", line 112, in _init_plugins
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime     raise NoMatches('No %r driver found, looking for %r' %
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime stevedore.exception.NoMatches: No 'neutron.service_plugins' driver found, looking for 'vpnaas'
2023-02-26 09:17:25.217 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime
2023-02-26 09:17:25.218 895152 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime [req-a32b0298-9d9f-49c9-a0fb-d914020d1edd - - - - -] Error loading class by class name: ValueError: Empty module name
```

There's more but it seems that with the installation I did the vpnaas is like non "existing" but I don't know how I should add or install it.

I tried several things like installing "pip install neutron-vpnaas", downloading the latest here https://tarballs.opendev.org/openstack/neutron-vpnaas/neutron-vpnaas-21.0.0.tar.gz and running the setup "sudo python3 setup.py install"...that probably broke my test environment, that I will have to setup completely new when I'm home.

But I thought it might be worth asking here as the installation is sometimes tricky and could have a cleaner structure. Maybe it's something obvious that other people encountered during the installation too.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Greetings

Edit after running `python3-neutron-vpnaas`:

When adding vpnaas to neutron the log shows:

```
The Log shows this: '2023-03-04 16:45:48.055 277379 INFO neutron.manager [req-493ddd6c-a9d0-417e-99c1-05d049749a71 - - - - -] Loading Plugin: vpnaas 2023-03-04 16:45:48.070 277379 WARNING stevedore.named [req-493ddd6c-a9d0-417e-99c1-05d049749a71 - - - - -] Could not load neutron_fwaas.services.firewall.service_drivers.agents.agents.FirewallAgentDriver 2023-03-04 16:45:48.070 277379 ERROR neutron.services.service_base [req-493ddd6c-a9d0-417e-99c1-05d049749a71 - - - - -] No providers specified for 'VPN' service, exiting'
```

the neutron.conf:

```
    [DEFAULT]
core_plugin = ml2
auth_strategy = keystone

#service_plugins = router,firewall_v2,vpnaas  ## when enable = failure
service_plugins = router,firewall_v2

allow_overlapping_ips = true
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:password@192.168.1.241


[agent]

root_helper = "sudo /usr/bin/neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf"



[cors]


[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://neutron:password@192.168.1.241/neutron


[ironic]


[keystone_authtoken]

www_authenticate_uri = http://192.168.1.241:5000
memcached_servers = 192.168.1.241:11211
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://192.168.1.241:5000
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = ----PWREMOVED-----

[nova]

region_name = RegionOne
auth_url = http://192.168.1.241:5000
password = ----PWREMOVED-----
project_domain_name = default
project_name = service
user_domain_name = default
username = nova


[oslo_concurrency]

lock_path = /var/lib/neutron/tmp


[oslo_messaging_amqp]


[oslo_messaging_kafka]


[oslo_messaging_notifications]


[oslo_messaging_rabbit]


[oslo_middleware]


[oslo_policy]


[privsep]


[quotas]


[ssl]


[service_providers]
service_provider = FIREWALL_V2:fwaas_db:neutron_fwaas.services.firewall.service_drivers.agents.agents.FirewallAgentDriver:default
```

As describes in the guide https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/zed/admin/vpnaas-scenario.html the /etc/neutron/neutron_vpnaas.conf looks like this:

```
[DEFAULT]


[service_providers]
service_provider = VPN:strongswan:neutron_vpnaas.services.vpn.service_drivers.ipsec.IPsecVPNDriver:default
```

And the l3_agent.ini:

```
[DEFAULT]

interface_driver = linuxbridge


[agent]
extensions = fwaas_v2,vpnaas


[network_log]


[ovs]


[vpnagent]
vpn_device_driver = neutron_vpnaas.services.vpn.device_drivers.strongswan_ipsec.StrongSwanDriver
```

**EDIT** after removing fwaas from service settings:

When fwaas is not configured in the corresponding files and vpnaas is configured, the neutron service starts but I think both servcies are not installed completely when just follwing these two documentations.
[FWaaS Openstack Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/zed/admin/fwaas-v2-scenario.html) and [VPNaaS Openstack Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/zed/admin/vpnaas-scenario.html). Because listing the options in the cli openstack .... the vpn option is not listet, from the fwaas the options were visible when enabled.

Comment: Try installing `python3-neutron-vpnaas` (in addition to `neutron-vpnaas-common`) as well, it contains the neutron extension. In my test env I get a DB error so I might have missed the neutron-manage step, but this should enable you to load the extension at least.

Comment: Now I got at least the plugin enabled after running the db-manage command. So you should be able to continue from there.

Comment: @eblock my test env is okay again. before adding vpnaas, i installed the 'python3-neutr...' that seems to be good, as I was able to runn the db-manage command without errors. 
But when vpnaas is added to the neutron.conf service_plugins, the service can't start anymore.

Comment: Please share your neutron.conf (edit the question) and also add the log there so it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: @eblock Thanks for the instructions. I'll remote the logs from the comments now.

Comment: So now it seems like your firewall plugin prevents neutron from starting. To see if you can get vpnaas to work I’d remove fwaas and see how far you get. I’ll try to enable both in my lab tomorrow, not sure what exactly is missing here. Did you reinstall the fw related packages as well after resetting your setup?

Comment: The packages that are installed for fwaas are `neutron-fwaas-common 
python3-neutron-fwaas` sadly the installation guide does not say something about packages that need to be installed neither the fwaas (v2) part nor the vpnaas.. thanks for testing. I'll try to disable fwaas to see if that helps.

Comment: So I was able to start both services, you just have to "read between the lines" as the docs don't seem to be complete. Basically, install all available packages of the service you try to enable (as we already figured out). Then combine the plugin and extension entries, each guide only covers one plugin, but you already figured that out according to your conf snippets. I followed the docs and edited `/etc/neutron/fwaas_driver.ini`, `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini` and added [service_providers] section to neutron.conf. then I could start the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally this seems to be working.Thank you eblock!
In order to have FWaaS and VPNaas running, i did the following:
Install the additional packages:

- python3-neutron-fwaas
- python3-neutron-vpnaas
- neutron-fwaas-common

and my configuration files:
/etc/neutron/neutron_vpnaas.conf & neutron_fwaas.conf --> nothing in it excep for the "headers" like [DEFAULT] etc..

/etc/neutron/neutron.conf

```
...
[DEFAULT]
service_plugins = router,firewall_v2,vpnaas
...
[service_providers]
service_provider = FIREWALL_V2:fwaas_db:neutron_fwaas.services.firewall.service_drivers.agents.agents.FirewallAgentDriver:default
service_provider = VPN:strongswan:neutron_vpnaas.services.vpn.service_drivers.ipsec.IPsecVPNDriver:default
```

/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini

```
...
[agent]
extensions = fwaas_v2

[fwaas]
firewall_l2_driver = noop
```

/etc/neutron/fwaas_driver.ini

```
...
[fwaas]
agent_version = v2
driver = neutron_fwaas.services.firewall.service_drivers.agents.drivers.linux.iptables_fwaas_v2.IptablesFwaasDriver
enabled = True
```

And don't forget /etc/neutron/l3_agent.ini:

```
...
[agent]
extensions = fwaas_v2,vpnaas
...
[vpnagent]
vpn_device_driver = neutron_vpnaas.services.vpn.device_drivers.strongswan_ipsec.StrongSwanDriver
```

I hope that's really all and I can now test and build what I need with it.

Comment: Can you create a bug report for the documentation at launchpad? Or I can do that as well, I have an account already.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could do that. I don't have an account and am really busy finishing my bachelor thesis currently.  Thank you again for all the help!

Comment: @eblock maybe you can have a look at my new question too [openstack VPN to cisco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684463/openstack-configure-a-vpnaas-ipsec-connection-to-a-cisco-1941)